# Taxonomy Term Path to Search

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, search

Running Drupal 7:

Problem: I have a vocabulary that contains a list of faculty, within each faculty member term page is a list of research interests (a separate vocabulary) that are clickable.  Currently they go to their individual term pages.

Goal: How can I make those "Research Interests" clickable and simply make it go to the search page with that term as the search query?

Answer (score 1):

I see two options to achieves this.

The first one is to alter the `page callback` for the `taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term` path through an implementation of [`hook_menu_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7). In the custom page callback, when displaying a term from your vocabulary, use `drupal_goto()` to redirect to the search page. And for terms in other vocabularies, you can re-use [`taxonomy_term_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.pages.inc/function/taxonomy_term_page/7) to preserve the original behavior.

The second option is to implement [`hook_entity_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7) to alter the `uri callback` of the `taxonomy term` entity type. In the custom URI callback, when getting the URI for a term of your vocabulary, returns the URI of the search page. For terms in other vocabularies, you can re-use [`taxonomy_term_uri()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_uri/7) to preserve the original behavior.